# php namespace auto-load directory

Tags: php, namespaces, spl-autoload-register

I've a class structure (tree) like this:

```
- garcha/
|   - html/
|       Tag.php
|       VTag.php
|       etc..
```

**What works:** (auto-loaded by *spl_autoload_register*)

```
use garcha\html;

$tag = new html\Tag('a');
```

**Can't work:**

```
use garcha\html;

$tag = new Tag('a');
```

**To achieve it without:** (I don't want to write each class file's `use` statement line by line, something to point to the class directory and use classes without parent namespace)

```
use garcha\html\Tag;
use garcha\html\VTag;
...
```

I don't like this way because, it's boring, need more time, less flexible (*you may change file structure, class name etc..*)

**In a nutshell:** I'm trying to auto-load namespaced class directory and use classes in it with unqualified names.

**Auto-loader function:**

```
class AutoLoader 
{
    protected static $pathes = array();

    /**
     * add pathes
     * 
     * @param string $path
     */
    public static function addPath($path) 
    {
        $path = realpath($path);

        if ($path) 
        {
            self::$pathes[] = $path . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
        }
    }

    /**
     * load the class
     * @param string $class
     * @return boolean
     */
    public static function load($class) 
    {
        $classPath = $class.'.php'; // Do whatever logic here

        foreach (self::$pathes as $path) 
        {
            if (is_file($path . $classPath)) 
            {
                require_once $path . $classPath;

                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

**Adding path:**

```
AutoLoader::addPath(BASE_PATH.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'vendor');
```

auto-loading works, the question is about how to handle

```
use garcha\html; // class directory
```

and use classes without leading `html`

```
$tag = new Tag('p'); // not $tag = new html\Tag('p');
```

Comment: what is your `self::$pathes` set to

Comment: Why not use the full namespace path? You'll have to change it if you change the path later, `use` or not

Comment: @Machavity imagine there is more than 10 classes in that directory, and writing 10 lines for each class is not cool :/

Comment: @GeorgeGarchagudashvili maybe add `html` in your autoloader to load all classes from `/html`

Comment: @GGio is it not loading everything from the directory anyways, just prepends to required class path.

Comment: @GeorgeGarchagudashvili add it to your pathes variable: `::addPath('garcha/html')`

Comment: yes that way it will work but this case is just example, there will be many class directories and it becomes bad idea for performance, for flexibility, making code hard to change.

Answer (score 0):

You could try different solutions:

**First:** you can add `garcha/html` in your `pathes` variable like `::addPath('garcha/html')`

**Second:** try to use the following code in your auto loader

```
foreach (glob("garcha/*.php") as $filename)
{
    require_once $filename;
}
```

`glob` basically will match all files that end with `.php` and then you can use them to either add them to your `pathes` variable or just include them.

**Note:** you would need to slightly modify your autoloader to use above loop in it.

**Edit:**
Try this:

```
public static function load($class) 
{
    // check if given class is directory
    if (is_dir($class)) {
       // if given class is directory, load all php files under it
       foreach(glob($class . '/*.php') as $filePath) {
          if (is_file($filePath)) 
          {
             require_once $filePath;

             return true;
          }
       }
    } else {
       // otherwise load individual files (your current code)
       /* Your current code to load individual class */
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is not what I want, because there also will be `garcha\validator`, `garcha\database`, etc.. including all the files within, does not seem to be good idea. Also it will not be worthy because I'll just simply use `html\Tag` or `Database\Connection`

Comment: If needed solution can't be done without loading all the files, I would continue working with current availabilities. Thank you very much, seems this would be the only solution, or writing use statement for each class

Comment: @GeorgeGarchagudashvili I am bookmarking this in case someone posts a valid solution. I would like to use it in my applications as well :). aba shen ici

Comment: გენაცვალე, მადლობა <3